# Gridview bug with adding a filter to a gridview populated by a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a .net webform with a simple data driven gridview:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtCodeSearch" runat="server" Width="250px"></asp:TextBox>
      <br />
<asp:Button ID="btnCodeSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" CssClass="button-tiny" 
        onclick="btnCodeSearch_Click" />

<asp:Gridview id="gvTest" runat="server">
<Columns>
<asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" HeaderText="Action" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Field1" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="Field2" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="CodeID" HeaderText="" ReadOnly="true" Visible="false" /> 
</Columns>
</asp:Gridview> 

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsTest" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SQLConn %>" 
            SelectCommand="SelectCodes" 
            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
            >
            <SelectParameters>
               <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="FooID" QueryStringField="FooID" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

1) On page load, the front end sqdatasource populates the gridview with a variable in the querystring, FooID

2) When the textbox above is filled with a code, and the button is pressed, I run the following in the codebehind:

```
 protected void btnCodeSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string CodeName = string.Empty;
            CodeName = txtCodeSearch.Text;

            string FooID= string.Empty;
            FooID = Request.QueryString["FooID"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CodeName))
            {
                dsTest.SelectParameters.Clear();
                dsTest.SelectCommand = "SelectCodesWithFilter";
                dsTest.SelectParameters.Add("FooID", FooID);
                dsTest.SelectParameters.Add("CodeName", CodeName);
            }

            else
            {
                dsTest.SelectParameters.Clear();
                dsTest.SelectCommand = "SelectCodes";

            }

            gvTest.DataBind();
        }
```

Which in a nutshell runs a different select statement in a stored proc to populate the gridview with an extra filter. If nothing is in the textbox, populate the gridview against the original stored proc

This all works perfectly. The issue is, the gridview has editing capability. If edit mode is engaged when the grid is populated from the first stored proc (SelectCodes), it works with no issues. If I filter the grid down and it is populated by the SECOND stored procedure (SelectCodesWithFilter) and I go into edit mode, it tells me that I'm trying to add too many parameters to the FIRST stored procedure.

I'm stumped, I can't figure out why it's doing that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why don't you use use the SqlCommand objects to then `AddWithValue` command fill a datatable using the SqlAdapter.. from there you are aware that you can do filtering on the datatable

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but I found* this piece of code to switch to a different query:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = "SELECT x FROM MyTable";
SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

I notice the DataBind() command on the SqlDataSource, before the one on the GridView. Would that make a difference for you?

*Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1535310.aspx?Changing+Select+Command+of+SQLDataSource+from+code+behind